# MVC - problem when uploading large files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

I'm working in MVC and I have view control for uploading document. My control is:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PutDoDatoteke, new { type="file"})%>
```

When I upload large file I get "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" error. I added

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="157286400"  />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

to my `web.config` file but i still get the same error. Is there any way to check file size on client side?

Comment: How large is the file? Does it work with smaller files? What sizes have you tested with?

Comment: It works with files up to 20MB, I have just read that IIS have limitation on upload files's size and that was problem.

Comment: Feel free to post the solution as an answer here so that it can help people with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was solution for my problem : http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on your local machine or on a hoster? Most Hosters do not allow you to overwrite this section in the Web.Config?

What you can do it read this setting in the action method and pass it to the view in viewbag.